# Working with Python and pickle to save complex data in object

Tags: python, list, pickle

I am experimenting with python to do a script for a program that works with python, and I need to save an object (with custom classes and arrays inside) to a file so that I can read it afterwards (so that I don't have to remake the object everytime, which takes hours)

I was reading in many forums that the easiest way to do that is to use pickle, but I am making a mistake in some place and I don't understand where...

Now, the code would be:

First I define this class:

```
class Issue_class:
    Title_ID = None
    Publisher_ID = None
    Imprint_ID = None
    Volume = None
    Format = None
    Color = None
    Original = None
    Rating = None
    Issue_Date_Month = None
    Issue_Date_Year = None
    Reprint = None
    Pages = None
    Issue_Title = None
    Number = None
    Number_str = None
    Synopsis = None
    Characters_ID = None
    Groups_ID = None
    Writer_ID = None
    Inker_ID = None
    Colorist_ID = None
    Letterer_ID = None
    CoverArtist_ID = None
    Penciller_ID = None
    Editor_ID = None
    Alternatives_ID = None
    Reprints_ID = None
    Story_ID = None
    Multi = None
    Multistories = None
```

then I define a list/array for this class:

```
Issuesdata = []
```

then during a loop I fill and append these to the list:

```
    Issuedata = Issue_class()

    Issuedata.Color = "unknown"
    Issuedata.Tagline = "none"
    Issuedata.Synopsis = "none"
    Issuedata.Format = "none"
    Issuedata.Publisher_ID = "none"
    Issuedata.Imprint_ID = -1
    Issuedata.Title_ID = -1
    Issuedata.Volume = "none"
    Issuedata.Number = -1
    Issuedata.Number_str = "none"
    Issuedata.Issue_Title = "none"
    Issuedata.Rating = -1
    Issuedata.Pages = -1
    Issuedata.Issue_Date_Year = 0
    Issuedata.Issue_Date_Month = 0
    Issuedata.Original = True
    Issuedata.Reprint = False
    Issuedata.Multi= True
    Issuedata.Letterer_ID = []
    Issuedata.Characters_ID = []
    Issuedata.Story_ID = []
    Issuedata.Groups_ID = []
    Issuedata.Writer_ID = []
    Issuedata.Penciller_ID = []
    Issuedata.Alternatives_ID = []
    Issuedata.Reprints_ID = []
    Issuedata.Inker_ID = []
    Issuedata.Colorist_ID = []
    Issuedata.Editor_ID = []
    Issuedata.CoverArtist_ID = []
    Issuedata.Multistories = []
```

Then I work with the data inside the object, and when it is complete, I append it to the list:

```
Issuesdata.append(Issuedata)
```

After that I print some info inside one of the objects in the list to be sure everything is ok:

```
print Issuesdata[3].Title_ID
print Issuesdata[3].Publisher_ID
print Issuesdata[3].Imprint_ID
print Issuesdata[3].Volume
print Issuesdata[3].Format
etc...
```

And everything is ok, the printed data is perfect

Now, I try to save the list to a file with:

```
filehandler = open("data.dat","wb")    
pickle.dump(Issuesdata,filehandler)
filehandler.close()
```

This create the file with info inside... but when I try to read it with:

```
file = open("data.dat",'rb')
Issuesdat = pickle.load(file)
file.close()
```

The Python console tells me "'module' object has no attribute 'Issue_class'"

The first thing I thought was that I was reading the file wrong... But then I open the saved file with notepad and inside it it was full of "wrong data", like name of files or name of classes outside the code... which makes me suspect I am dumping the data wrong in the file...

Am I using pickle wrong?

Comment: `pickle` isn't designed for human-readable files. Is `Issue_class` available where you're trying to read the data back into the program? Could you give a [mcve]?

Comment: I forget to tell the two last pieces of code are one after the other, in the same module... so the two of them see the "class definition"

Comment: Also, it's worth noting that your class design seems unwise - I'd recommend you provide an `__init__` with parameters, and break related parameters into objects of their own (see e.g. https://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/smells/long-parameter-list).

Comment: I know the data is not supposed to be readable, but some things as strings can be read all the same... And they are completely wrong strings NOT in the list... 
Ok, I will make a simpler and complete code with the problem :)

Comment: @Xellos Nakama I tried the above, put everything in a single file...runs without any error on my system. are you sure Issue_class is present in the context where the pickle is being loaded?

Comment: try this to save pickle
`with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(issues_data, f)`

and this to load it back:
`kosher_dill = pickle.load(open(filename,"rb"))`

Comment: I tried the Bedi E code, and it print the same "'module' object has no attribute 'Issue_class'"

Comment: I found the error, I had to define the class in the main module, and not in the module I was working in... It was a class defining problem after all... I don't understand why pickle can't see the class when it is called in that module :/

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I found the problem... It seems you have to define the class of your object in the main module for pickle to see it... I had it defined in the module I was working and calling the pickle command...

Answer (score 0):

Try using `pandas` library with simple functions like:

`DataFrame.to_pickle(file-path)` to save **pandas Dataframe** in pickle.

`pandas.read_pickle(file-path)` to read pickle file.

Here you can find **pandas** reference [to_pickle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_pickle.html) [read_pickle](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_pickle.html).